# Static Highcharts graphic with csv data and dynamic footnote

Tags: csv, highcharts

I have a highcharts graphic, which consists of a static javascript code and a dynamic preformatted HTML text (pre) containing CSV data. (The dynamic text with the CSV data is updated daily, the Javascript code remains unchanged).
Now I would like to add a footnote, e.g. using "caption", which should also be dynamic.
How can I make the footer dynamic?
I had the idea to write the footnote into the CSV data and read it out of there, but I didn't succeed.

The jsfiddle example is here:
https://jsfiddle.net/martindfurrer/r4tjdka9/

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="background: pink; width: 400px; height: 300px"></div>

<!--dynamic csv data from other source-->

<pre id="csv" style="display:none">
"utcdate;"value"
"1";"181"
"2";"225"
"3";"171"
"4";"188"
"5";"246"
"6";"98"
"7";"48"
</pre>

<script type='text/javascript'>

// static javascript code
Highcharts.chart('container', {
   title: {
        text: 'Corona Virus cases'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Data input from CSV'
    },
    data: {
        csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML
    },
    series: [ {
        name: 'Infection rate',
        type: 'column',
    }],
    caption: {
       text: 'The Javascript code is static, the csv data is dynamic. This text should also be dynamic, i.e. some sort of variable',
    }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example a `load` event to update the caption with dynamic content:

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function() {
                this.update({
                    caption: {
                        text: document.getElementById('dynamicCaption').innerHTML
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Or just use a HTML reference in a `text` property:

```
    caption: {
        text: document.getElementById('dynamicCaption').innerHTML,
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zbkhm41r/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/caption.text

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

Comment: I have another question, see below.

Comment: Hi @Martin F., You should create a new question for that. In such case, you need to get the CSV data from external source in the `load` event and update the chart.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek. I asked a new question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64991611/static-highcharts-graphic-with-external-csv-data-and-dynamic-footnote. 
Can you answer me there and give me an example?