# Static Highcharts graphic with external csv data and dynamic footnote

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

I have a highcharts graphic, which consists of a static javascript code and external dynamic csv data. (The external CSV data is updated daily, the Javascript code remains unchanged). Now I would like to add a footnote, e.g. using "caption", which should also be dynamic. How can I make the footer dynamic?

The jsfiddle example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/martindfurrer/kx5ebgny/

```
caption: {
   text: 'The Javascript code is static, the data is in a csv file. This text 
      should also be dynamic, i.e. should be read out of the csv file.'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get csv data in `load` event and update your chart with a formatted resposne, for example:

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function() {
                fetch('https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/vs-load.csv')
                    .then(response => response.text())
                    .then(data => {
                        this.update({
                            caption: {
                                text: data
                            }
                        });
                    });
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s8dq7b3L/)

**API Reference:** [api.highcharts.com](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update)